# Saving data from Ext.data.Store to Postgres database not via WFS-T

Tags: openlayers, geoserver, extjs

Technique of spatial data editing via web browser described in this tutorial is extreamly easy:
http://workshops.opengeo.org/geoext/wfs/index.html#geoext-wfs

Ext, GeoExt, OpenLayers Geoserver and WFS-T do all dirty job, and you do not have to code anything server side. All UPDATE, INSERT & DELETE queries to database are done by via WFS-T.

Is there something like this for non-spatial data? What will handle store-to-database communication as good as WFS-T? Abovementioned solution is also good for non-spatial data but I would like to avoid using geoserver all the time:)

Comment: This is a question for Stackoverflow.

Comment: You are looking for a web framework, like Django.

Comment: Right - I think I will use Symfony + doctrine (as it is something I know), but I was searching something light. I asked here as most of stackoverflow folks might not know WFS-T. I will try there as well, anyway.

Comment: Here I started with Django + Tastypie = REST API, consumed with Extjs datastore with rest proxy. Now I'm leaving Tastypie to use only Django consumed by ExtDirect, take a look at that. I serve the vector this way also, Extjs take them and convert to OpenLayers features. I use Geoserver for rasters.

Comment: Thanks for advices. I have heard about GeoDjango: mayby it is even easyer with it. Unfortunately I do not now Python to much:(

Comment: If you are familiar with PHP, then you might find https://github.com/loiane/extjs4-mvc-json-crud-php-mysql easy to follow. As for the use of MySQL, simply replace them with PostgreSQL-specific calls.

Comment: Thanks! I will go through it. It is a pity that there is no documentation:)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of tools for loading data into PostGIS.

1. [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) utility in [GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/index.html) is a commandline utility
2. [QGIS](http://qgis.org/) is a desktop GIS client that can do CRUD on PostGIS
3. FME is commercial software that can also do data editing in PostGIS

Lots to choose from

Comment: It is not what I am looking for. I need a connection between ext grid and postgres. In the example given, this connection is maintained by WFS-T.

Comment: Pay attention to the question.